# Значение += в Java

Tags: java

Что значит += в этой строчке?
s += (y = v.eval(i++));

Comment: i = i+1;

y = v.eval(i);

s = s+y; 

если уж так пошло =)

Comment: @Gorets вообще-то в примере стоит постинкремент. Поэтому i = i+1 должно быть в конце

Comment: Я не уверен насчёт Java, но в C# данное выражение равносильно такому:

    var iOld = i;
    var iNew = i+1;
    i = iNew;
    var evalRes = v.Eval(iOld);
    y = evalRes;
    s = s + evalRes;

Разницу можно наблюдать в случае, если v.eval модифицирует `i`.

Answer (score 2):

s = s + (y = v.eval(i++));